# Run Win on Android tablet then run Android studio

Tags: android, windows, virtual-machine

I want to programming on my tablet when I am on a trip, but I can't use laptop. Is there way to use Android tablet - run virtual win 7 than install Android studio ?

Comment: use **teamViewr** and keep your laptop on and charging

Comment: Is there offline resolution ?

Comment: Yes, keep your laptop with yourself

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about whether you can install virtual windows 7 on your tablet. As you are going to trip, then there are chances that you might be having internet connection on your tablet. If it's so, you can visit [AppInventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/) here you can create android project online.
Hope, it will help you.